# Is it possible to add a web resource to canvas app

Tags: paypal, powerapps

I have created a canvas power app. I am trying to use the paypal API: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/ ,which gives you html to embed into your code. I know Power Apps is a no-code platform, but are you be able to connect a Canvas app to a Web Resource with html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot use javascript directly in your canvas app but there is something called [PowerApps component framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/component-framework/component-framework-for-canvas-apps). you can use PCF to have coded component in your canvas app.

There is an [pcf gallery](https://pcf.gallery/) as well which contains community crated pcf controls which could be directly used.

In addition, it is not required if you want to consume 3rd party api that you use javascript. There is something called custom connectors/ or out of box connectores in [power automate](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/), you can call power automate (flows) from your canavas app and consume output/results from your flow.
[Take a look at this connector article](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/paypal-connect-flow.rst)